# Read list of different types from istream into vector

Tags: c++, vector, types

I'm trying to read text of the following format from an `istream` (e.g. `std::cin`):

```
<type_code>
<n>
<elem_0> <elem_1> ... <elem_n-1>
```

where

- First line `<type_code>`: 0=`int`, 1=`double`, 2=`char`, 3=`std::string`;
- Second line `<n>` is the number of elements in the list;
- Third line contains the actual elements, separated by a space character.

For example, the following is a list of 5 `std::string`s:

```
3
5
apple banana orange kiwi tomato
```

Intuitive I did:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void Work(std::vector<T> &A) {
    // do something ...
}

int main() {
    int type_code, len;
    std::cin >> type_code >> len;
    std::vector<int> ilist;
    std::vector<double> dlist;
    std::vector<char> clist;
    std::vector<std::string> slist;

    switch (type_code) {
        case 0:
            ilist.resize(len);
            for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                std::cin >> ilist[i];
            }
            Work(ilist);
            break;
        case 1:
            dlist.resize(len);
            for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                std::cin >> dlist[i];
            }
            Work(dlist);
            break;
        case 2:
            clist.resize(len);
            for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                std::cin >> clist[i];
            }
            Work(clist);
            break;
        case 3:
            slist.resize(len);
            for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                std::cin >> slist[i];
            }
            Work(slist);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Due to the uncertainty of type until runtime, I have to instantiate 4 vector of different type. This produce duplicate code and more objects than I need (since eventually only 1 vector will be used).

What's the best way of handling here?

Comment: You can use a template for the reading code too, that removes the duplication. You can delay instantiating your vector until you know what type you need. Just moving the vector declarations into the switch cases would achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(**Note:** Please also refer to answers by [@Jake Schmidt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61940550/8311608) and [@anastaciu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61940289/8311608). They provide great examples of C++17 `std::any` and `std::variant`)

---

I figure out that putting everything in a template function fits my need just well.

C++ is statically typed (whatever that means) so you have to write that `switch` statement anyway and instantiate the template function 4 times with explicit type arguments (and call them). It's not like python where you can write `type_arr=[int,float,str]` and use `type_code` to index it.

btw. it's a demo for insertion sort.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>

template<typename T>
void print_vec(std::vector<T> vec) {
    for (auto &e : vec) std::cout << e << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void Work(std::istream &in, int len) {
    std::vector<T> vec(len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) in >> vec[i];
    for (int i = 1; i < len; ++i) {
        auto insert_it = std::upper_bound(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + i, vec[i]);
        std::rotate(vec.rend() - i - 1, vec.rend() - i, std::make_reverse_iterator(insert_it));
        print_vec(vec);
    }
}

void read(std::istream &in) {
    int type_code, len;
    in >> type_code >> len; // omitting garbage input check
    switch (type_code) {
        case 0:
            Work<int>(in, len);
            break;
        case 1:
            Work<double>(in, len);
            break;
        case 2:
            Work<char>(in, len);
            break;
        case 3:
            Work<std::string>(in, len);
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "err" << std::endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main() {
//    std::istringstream iss{"0\n6\n21 25 49 25 16 8"};
//    read(iss);
    read(std::cin);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since C++17 you can use `std::any`

```
std::vector<std::any> vectorName;
```

Another option can be `std::variant`, but here you have to specify the types the vector can hold as opposed to `std::any`.

Answer (score 2):

`std::variant` should work nicely for this... (requires C++17)

```
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void Work(std::vector<T>& v) {
    // do more stuff
}

// this is a type that will hold either a vector<int>, vector<double>, etc, or nothing
using variantoftypes = std::variant<std::vector<int>,
                std::vector<double>,
                std::vector<char>,
                std::vector<std::string>>;

template<typename T>
void doStuff(std::istream& in, variantoftypes& v, int len) {

    //assign v to hold a vector<T>
    v = std::vector<T>();

    //get the vector it's holding out...
    std::vector<T> &v_alias = std::get<std::vector<T>>(v); 

    // now v_alias will behave like you want it to
    v_alias.resize(len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        std::cin >> v_alias[i];
    }

    // work with the alias
    Work(v_alias);

}



int main() { 
    variantoftypes v;

    int type_code, len;
    std::cin >> type_code >> len;

    switch (type_code) {
        case 0:
            doStuff<int>(std::cin, v, len);
            break;
        case 1:
            doStuff<double>(std::cin, v, len);
            break;
        case 2: 
            doStuff<char>(std::cin, v, len);
            break;
        case 3:
            doStuff<std::string>(std::cin, v, len);
            break;
    }

}
```